# ¿Porque es necesario usar el comando cin.ignore() después de usar "cin >>" y luego recién usar el cin.getline(char*,size)?

Tags: c++

(Me disculpo por el título, soy difícil de explicarme ahí, pero en la descripción todo se entenderá)

Hoy durante un proyecto que hice, se me presentó un error que nunca me había pasado antes, y la verdad no recurriría a esta comunidad si no fuera porque ni mi magíster de programación sabe porqué ocurre este error.

El error ocurre en esta porción de código:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char frase[100];
    int opcion;
    std::cout << "Ingrese una opcion: ";
    std::cin >> opcion;
    switch (opcion)
    {
    case 1:
        std::cout << "Ingrese la frase:";//El programa ignora este comando
        std::cin.getline(frase, 100); //<--por algún motivo
        std::cout << "La frase es: " << frase << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Opcion no valida..." << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

SALIDA:

> Ingrese una opcion: 1
>   Ingrese la frase:La frase es:
>   Presione una tecla para continuar . . .

Como se puede ver, en la salida, lee correctamente el `int opcion`, pero por alguna razón ignora completamente el `getline`;
Buscando por internet, encontré la solución:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <windows.h>
//#include <string.h>
//#include <fstream>
//#include "ClaseA.h"

int main()
{
    char frase[100];
    int opcion;
    std::cout << "Ingrese una opcion: ";
    std::cin >> opcion;
    std::cin.ignore(); //<-- la solución, poner esto justo después de usar
    switch (opcion)    //    el 'cin >>'
    {
    case 1:
        std::cout << "Ingrese la frase:";
        std::cin.getline(frase, 100);
        std::cout << "La frase es: " << frase << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Opcion no valida..." << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

SALIDA:

> Ingrese una opcion: 1
>   Ingrese la frase:Los programadores no duermen
>   La frase es: Los programadores no duermen
>   Presione una tecla para continuar . . .

sin embargo, hay cosas que no entiendo, por ejemplo:
**¿por qué ocurre este error?**
**¿Por qué es obligatorio usar ese comando después de un `cin >>`?**

Simplemente quiero saber porque ocurre esto.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ¿por qué ocurre este error?

No es un error sino el comportamiento esperado. Me explico.

`cin` dispone de ciertas ayudas que simplifican la lectura de datos. Así, el siguiente código:

```
int a, b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
std::cout << a << ' ' << b;
```

funcionará correctamente independientemente de que exista un espacio entre los dos números, veinte espacios, una docena de saltos de línea o una combinación. En estos casos `cin` es capaz de ignorar una serie de caracteres identificados como separadores.

En este caso, `cin` descarta los separadores que se encuentren **antes** de la secuencia que pretendes leer. Los separadores que haya después, y esto es **importante**, incluidos los saltos de línea, se mantienen en el buffer de entrada.

Sin embargo `cin.getline` no dispone de esas ayudas y el motivo es que no le estás pidiendo a `cin` que te lea una simple cadena de caracteres, es decir, algo tal que:

```
std::string cadena;
std::cin >> cadena;
```

En este caso en `cadena` se almacenaría una secuencia de caracteres hasta llegar a un separador (generalmente espacio, tabulador o salto de línea).

Tu le estás diciendo a `cin` que tiene que leer **todos** los caracteres que encuentre hasta el primer salto de línea que se encuentre... y resulta que, si no limpias el buffer, `cin` detecta que el primer caracter leido es un salto de línea, por lo que deja de leer.

El método `getline` no puede descartar ese salto de línea porque entonces la función tendría problemas para leer líneas que sí pueden estar vacías (en ese caso se descartaría el salto de línea y se leería la línea siguiente a la pedida).

Así pues, si antes de usar `getline` has usado el operador de extracción `>>`, acuerdate de usar `ignore` para descartar el salto de línea que se ha quedado en el buffer de entrada.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿por qué ocurre este error?

Cuando tú haces el uso del `cin >>` en tu código, a la hora de introducir el valor que se almacenará en tu variable `opcion` en realidad lo que haces (a veces sin darte cuenta) es almacenar el valor dando al <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Ese <kbd>Enter</kbd> que introduces, en realidad es un salto de línea (lo que conocemos como el **\n**) así que en realidad lo que haces es esto:

> Ingrese una opcion:
> x(número cualquiera)**\n**

Una vez que haces eso el salto de línea queda en el buffer de entrada y la función `getline` dejará de funcionar ya que solamente almacena los valores que le asignemos hasta el salto de línea (**\n**).

Para solucionar este problema tienes que limpiar de alguna manera el buffer de entrada. Lo cuál puedes hacer con `ignore`, lo que hace es ignorar (borrar) el caracter de salto de línea.

Puede ser que si alguien introduce en el buffer de entrada la variable numérica `opcion`, junto a otros caracteres ya sea letras o espacios en blanco, lo recomendable sería usar `cin.ignore(x, '\n')`, de esta forma eliminará hasta el salto de línea o hasta `x` caracteres.

Por ejemplo, si pones en el buffer de entrada `5__` ("_" como espacio en blanco), deberías usar `cin.ignore(2, '\n')` para que limpie los dos espacios en blanco.

Esto puede cambiar dependiendo del Entorno de Desarrollo de Programación que uses, por ejemplo en NetBeans si uso `cin.ignore(1,'\n')`, el `getline` no se me ejecutará después de dos espacios y no uno como en otros puede funcionar.

Ahora, si alguien pone en el buffer de entrada `55____________`..., con varios espacios, entonces lo que usaremos es el `ignore` con el mayor número de caracteres que puedan usarse en el stream, para eso usaremos `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')`.

Otra cosa que puedes mejorar en tu código, es el uso del `namespace std` que te evitará usar el std con el operador de ámbito `std::`, después de la biblioteca `<iostream>` pones `using namespace std` y si usarás librerías de C en C++, trata de usarlos con la letra **c** al inicio de las bibliotecas para que sepas diferenciarlos, es decir, en vez de usar `stdlib.h` trata de usar `cstdlib`.

Answer (score 0):

Algunas veces el programa guarda datos en la entrada eso es lo que le ocurrió a tu programa para limpiar el buffer usa esto:

> fflush(stdin);.

Colocalo después de **case 1**: y tu programa funcionará correctamente.

Comment: La respuesta que acabas de dar es para C. También podría servir para C++ pero el asunto es más delicado: no puedes pretender que dos funciones diferentes se lleven bien juntas (las de entrada de C y las de C++). Además lo que sugieres es [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/226500/169744). Puede que en algunos compiladores funcione, pero sigue sin ser portable.