# ¿para que sirve flush en c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, stdin, stdout

tengo una duda que es cuando pongo una estructura demasiado grande (en la que tengo que poner el `fflush(stdin)` el programa me dice que `fflush(stdin)` no está declarada.

Me pregunto al poner un `flush` detras de todo el `cout` me haría lo mismo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Introducción

Los dispositivos de salida tienen, básicamente, dos modos de funcionamiento:

- Acceso directo: Todo lo que le pases al *stream* de salida se lleva al dispositivo de salida (se guarda en un archivo, se envía por el socket, se envía a la impresora, ...)
- Acceso por buffer: Dado que la interacción con los dispositivos de salida suele ser bastante lenta se puede optar por usar un buffer que actúa de intermediario. Cada vez que tu envías algo al *stream* de salida, la información se almacena en el buffer y solo ante determinados eventos se procede a volcar el contenido del buffer en el dispositivo de salida.

Pues bien, la función `fflush` sirve, precisamente, para forzar ese volcado de información al dispositivo de salida. Esto implica que en el caso de conexiones sin buffer su utilidad es nula.

Ahora bien, si te fijas verás que únicamente estoy hablando de dispositivos de salida, mientras que `stdin` es un *stream* **de entrada**.

Una muy mala costumbre tan extendida que hasta la enseñan en algunos cursos e incluso la universidad, es usar `fflush` para vaciar el *stream* de entrada. Lo de que sea una muy mala costumbre no lo digo yo, sino la propia documentación de [`fflush`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/):

> In all other cases, the behavior depends on the specific library implementation. In some implementations, flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (**but this is not portable expected behavior**).

Es decir, que si a ti te funciona `fflush(stdin)` es simplemente porque usas una versión de la librería estándar que lo soporta... pero es algo que puede dejar de funcionar simplemente actualizando la versión del compilador o cambiando la versión de C++ (recordemos que actualmente tenemos C++98, C++03, C++11, C++14, C++17 y otra más que está en camino, C++20).

**Vale, no debemos usar `fflush(stdin)`... ¿Cómo limpiamos entonces el *stream* de entrada?**

Lamentablemente no hay previsto un mecanismo estándar para realizar esta tarea, aunque la alternativa más utilizada es la siguiente:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) ;
```

El código anterior descarta todos los caracteres de `stdin` hasta que se encuentra con `EOF`, símbolo que indica que has llegado al final del buffer.

Este código se puede decorar para ofrecer una funcionalidad más completa, por ejemplo descartar todo hasta el primer salto de línea:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
{
  if( ch == '\n' ) break;
}
```

Lo más recomendable sería encapsular este código en una función, pero eso ya corre a cuenta del interesado.

Vale, lo comentado hasta ahora solo ha servido para explicar por qué es una mala idea usar `fflush(stdin)`, ahora vamos con las preguntas:

> me pregunto al poner un flush detras de todo el cout me haria lo mismo.

`fflush` es una función heredada de C y, como tal, **no es compatible** con clases propias de C++.

`std::cout` dispone de un método `flush` que sirve exactamente para lo que estás preguntando:

```
std::cout << "Hola";
std::cout.flush();
```

### Bonus

Por si te lo estás preguntando, a diferencia de `stdio`, `std::cin` sí que dispone de un mecanismo para limpiar el buffer interno, a función en cuestión se llama `ignore()` y lo normal es encontrarla así:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
```

La función `ignore` admite dos argumentos:

- El máximo de caracteres a descartar.
- Un caracter que actúe de tope.

[`numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) es una plantilla de C++ que te ofrece información sobre los diferentes tipos de datos. En este caso, el método `max` está devolviendo el número más alto que puede almacenarse en una variable de tipo `int`.

En resumen, lo que hace ese código es descartar todos los caracteres que se encuentre hasta el primer salto de línea. Si no hay ningún salto de línea el código solo se detendrá cuando el buffer se haya vaciado completamente.

### Bonus 2

Al programar en C++ nos encontramos con que podemos usar indistintamente `stdin` y `std::cin` o `stdout` y `std::cout`. Lamento comunicarte que combinar sus usos es una malísima idea.

Por defecto no da ningún problema porque cada pareja de *streams* está sincronizada. Esto evita que puedan aparecer textos mezclados al mezclar sus usos pero tiene como desventaja que el acceso la entrada/salida desde C++ es más lenta que al programar en C.

Por supuesto, C++, como buena navaja suiza que es, permite desactivar esta sincronía. Para ello basta con ejecutar la siguiente línea:

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Desde ese momento la entrada salida pura de C++ (`std::cin` y `std::cout`) será muchísimo más rápida que su homóloga de C, algo por otro lado lógico y normal, pues no olvidemos que, por ejemplo, `scanf` tiene que interpretar una cadena de caracteres para saber qué y cómo debe leer la información de entrada.

Así pues, dado que esta línea puede (o no) encontrarse en cualquier punto del programa, incluso en código que no hemos escrito nosotros, conviene evitar mezclar los usos. Yo sugeriría usar únicamente las clases de C++, pues son más seguras y el código queda más legible.

Comment: Detalle, en la ejecución normal del programa nunca obtienes EOF. Solo aparece si rediriges la entrada, lees un archivo o con [alguna combinación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4702082/13419694).