# ERROR en codigo, puede ser el compilador?, estoy utilizando Dev C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, struct

Obtengo los siguientes errores:

> *linea 47 col. 9 [Error] jump to case label [-fpermissive].*
>
> *linea 31 col. 5 [Error] crosses initialization of 'main():: imagen img [dim_imagen]'.*

¿A qué se deben estos errores?, ¿Se debe al uso de una estructura para el segundo error?.

para el primer error, C++ me lo indica en el default, pero no entiendo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
/*Escribir un programa que permita guardar datos de imagenes. De cada imagen se debe guardar:
Nombre, ancho en pixeles, alto en pixeles y tamaño en Kb.
El programa debe almacenar hasta 700 imagenes (avisar cuando la capacidad esté llena).
Debe permitir las opciones: añadir una nueva ficha, ver todas las fichas (Numero y nombre de cada imagen), buscar la ficha de un cierto nombre.*/
 
int main (){
    int elector, dim_imagen;
    cout << "FICHERO DE IMAGENES\n\nOpciones\n";
    printf ("%c 1. A%cadir nueva ficha\n%c 2. Ver todas los ficheros de imagenes\n%c 3. Buscar una ficha seg%cn nombre\n", 175, 164, 175, 175, 163); cin >> elector;
    switch (elector){ //Eleccion.
        case 1: //Añadir ficha
            cout << "Cantidad de 'imagenes a agregar': "; cin >> dim_imagen;
            fflush(stdin);
            
            struct imagen  //Arreglo de imagenes[].
            {
            char titulo[40];
            int ancho;
            int largo;
            int tamano;
            }img[dim_imagen];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < dim_imagen; i++){
                cout << endl << i << endl << "Nombre del archivo: "; cin.getline (img[i].titulo, 40 ,'\n');
                cout << "Ancho de la imagen: "; cin >> img[i].ancho;
                cout << "Alto de la imagen: "; cin >> img[i].largo;
                cout << "Tamano: "; cin >> img[i].tamano;
                cout << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
            break;ev
        /*case 2: //Ver todos los ficheros
            break; 
        case 3: //Ficha segun nombre
            break;*/
        default:
            do{
                if (elector > 3 || elector <= 0){
                    printf ("%c 1. A%cadir nueva ficha\n%c 2. Ver todas los ficheros de imagenes\n%c 3. Buscar una ficha seg%cn nombre\n", 175, 164, 175, 175, 163);
                    cin >> elector;
                }
            }while (elector > 3 || elector <= 0);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5685578/13419694), ambos errores significan que estás creando variables dentro de un case.

Una solución simple es crear un nuevo [`Scope`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) rodeando el código en los casos entre llaves. Así:

```
switch (...){
    case 1:
    {
        ...
        break;
    }
    ...
    default:
    {
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Una mejor decisión que hará el código más legible consiste en mover el contenido de cada caso a su propia función.

Por cierto, luego de un `break` aparece `ev`. Quizá fue un error al copiar el código, asegúrate que en tu editor no esté.

---

Además, `fflush(stdin)` es comportamiento indefinido. No lo deberías usar.

Mezclar el estilo de entrada de C++ con el de C tampoco es buena idea. Es posible que los buffers no estén sincronizados y obtengas efectos indeseados. Hay [una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/226500/169744) al respecto.

- Si usas funciones de C por `printf`, desde C++20 existe la [librería de formato](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format). Puedes usarla como alternativa.
- Si necesitas ignorar entrada de un [istream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore), mejor usa ignore. Más información sobre [streams](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) aquí.