# ¿Pueden encontrar el error? C+

Tags: c++

Ejecuto el programa, cuando entra en el primer for este no avanza hacia buscar el numero mayor, solo se queda estancado en salario: y procede a cerrarse.
Cual es el error que se presenta? No lo logro encontrar.
No sé si se encuentra en las condicionales o tiene que ver con algo del buffer.
Cuando ingreso salario lo hago como, ejemplo: 3000000, supongo que eso no tiene que afectar, sigue siendo 'float'.
Necesito hacer espacio para que me deje enviar la pregunta, lo siento si tienes que leer esto.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    int cant_emp;
    char crg[] = {}; 
    
    cout << "Cantidad de empleados: "; cin >> cant_emp; 
    
    struct empleados{
        char nombre[20];
        int edad;
        float salario;
    }emp[cant_emp];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < cant_emp; i++){ //Ingreso de datos
        fflush(stdin);
        cout << i+1 << endl << "Nombre: "; cin.getline(emp[i].nombre, 20, '\n');
        
        do{ //Edad
            cout << "Edad: "; cin >> emp[i].edad;
            if (emp[i].edad<=17 && emp[i].edad > 0){
                cout << "Debes ser mayor de edad: "; cin >> emp[i].edad;
            }
            if (emp[i].edad<=0){
                cout <<"Tu edad debe ser un numero positivo distinto de 0: "; cin >> emp[i].edad;
            }
        }while(emp[i].edad<18);

        cin.ignore();
        do{ //Salario
            cout << "Salario: "; cin >> emp[i].salario; //Aqui el programa se detiene.
        }while(emp[i].salario <= 0);

        if (emp[i].salario > 3000000){
            strcat(crg, "Directivo");
        }
        else{
            if (emp[i].salario <= 3000000 && emp[i].salario > 1000000){
                strcat(crg, "Senior");
            }
            else{
                if (emp[i].salario <= 1000000 && emp[i].salario >= 400000){
                    strcat(crg, "Junior");
                }               
                else{
                    if (emp[i].salario > 80000 && emp[i].salario < 4000000){
                        strcat(crg, "Practicante"); 
                    }
                    else{
                        strcat(crg, "En serio, estas en esta empresa por tan poco dinero?");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    for (int j = 0;  j < cant_emp; j++){
        fflush(stdin);
        cout << j+1 << endl;
        cout << "Nombre: " << emp[j].nombre << endl;
        cout << "Edad:" << emp[j].edad << endl;
        cout << "Salario :" << emp[j].salario << endl << endl;
        cout << "Cargo: " << crg;
        }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Al contrario, no veo que se cierre nada sino que [se ejecuta infinitamente](https://bit.ly/3mqig9u). Claramente es porque queda un salto de línea luego de leer el número de empleados. Danos la entrada con la que estás probando a ver si obtenemos el mismo resultado.

Comment: Por cierto, no deberías usar `fflush(stdin)`. [Más información](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/226500/169744).

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en las líneas como esta:

```
strcat(crg, "Directivo");
```

En un compilador como gcc recibes **Segmentation Fault**.

`crg` es un arreglo vacío. Los arreglos son de tamaño fijo. No se pueden modificar.

Llegado a cierto punto, `strcat` lee una dirección de memoria que no debería y obtienes ese error, una excepción o simplemente el programa crashea.

---

Solución:

- Dale al arreglo `crg` un tamaño más grande, lo suficiente como para no tener problemas.
- Estás usando C++ en el año 2023. Considera usar la [librería de cadenas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) en lugar de usar las viejas funciones de C.

  Con esta opción sugiero que reemplaces los arreglos de caracteres por [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), `strcat` por el operador [`+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) o [`append`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append). También tiene su propia alternativa a [`cin.getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: La alternativa a cin.getline puede ser getline()? o cin.get?

Comment: @MatíasBilz la alternativa a `cin.getline` es la función `getline` a secas. Se usa así: `getline(cin, string)`. `cin.get` no consume el delimitador.