# Como acomodar el do while

Tags: dev-c++

estudio ingeniería pero me tocaron los profesores mas barcos que existen por lo que empece a estudiar por mi cuenta y por lo que prácticamente soy nuevo en esto de la programación y estaba haciendo un programa del método numérico de la secante, el programa básicamente debería de hacer unas operaciones y comparar el resultado (xn1) con el error aproximado (eo = 0.00001) hasta que sea igual o menor pero no se donde ponerle el do while para que haga las iteraciones que necesito que en este caso son 9, así como esta el programa solo hace 2 iteraciones:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    float xn, sn, xn1, fxn1, sn1, fxn, fpxn, fsumaxs, sumaxs, eo = 0.00001;
    
    cout<<"Programa para el metodo de la secante";
    cout<<"\nIntroduce tu Xo: "; cin>>xn;
    cout<<"Introduce tu So: "; cin>>sn;
        
    sumaxs = xn + sn;
    fxn = xn*tan(xn)-1;
    fsumaxs = sumaxs*tan(sumaxs)-1;
    fpxn = ((fsumaxs)-fxn)/sn;
    xn1 = xn - (fxn)/(fpxn);
    fxn1 = xn1*tan(xn1)-1;
    sn1 = xn - xn1;
    
    cout.precision(7);
    cout<<"Xo: "<<xn;
    cout<<"\nSo: "<<sn;
    cout<<"\nXo + So: "<<sumaxs;
    cout<<"\nf(Xo): "<<fxn;
    cout<<"\nf(Xo+So): "<<fsumaxs;
    cout<<"\nXn+1: "<<xn1;
    cout<<"\nf(Xn+1): "<<fxn1;
    
    
    if(xn1>eo){
    
        fflush(stdin);  
        xn = xn1;
        sn = sn1;
        
            sumaxs = xn + sn;
            fxn = xn*tan(xn)-1;
            fsumaxs = sumaxs*tan(sumaxs)-1;
            fpxn = ((fsumaxs)-fxn)/sn;
            xn1 = xn - (fxn)/(fpxn);
            fxn1 = xn1*tan(xn1)-1;
            sn1 = xn - xn1;
      
            cout.precision(7);
            cout<<"\nXo: "<<xn;
            cout<<"\nSo: "<<sn;
            cout<<"\nXo + So: "<<sumaxs;
            cout<<"\nf(Xo): "<<fxn;
            cout<<"\nf(Xo+So): "<<fsumaxs;
            cout<<"\nXn+1: "<<xn1;
            cout<<"\nf(Xn+1): "<<fxn1;
            
            fflush(stdin);  
            xn = xn1;
            sn = sn1;
                
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, podrías incluir un enlace o una breve explicación del algoritmo? No me refiero al código que escribiste.

Comment: Por cierto, evita usar `fflush(stdin)` o con otros streams de entrada. Si necesitas consumir o descartar entrada, puedes usar `cin.ignore()` o `cin.get`. [Más información](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/226500/169744).