# Como hago para arreglar este problema con el salto de linea o que no salen todos los numeros? Lenguaje C

Tags: c, bucles, imprimir, salto-de-linea

En el ejercicio me piden que pase los grados farenheit a celsius y que los imprima, yo arranco desde los 32 grados farenheit hasta los 100 grados. pero a la hora de imprimir como 68 veces los grados F y C, se me saltan los primeros grados y salta directo a los 50 F.
Vi que si no uso el salto de linea (/n) el problema no sucede. Pero necesito usarlo para que sea entendible el ejercicio y no se imprima uno alado del otro.

````
   grados Celsius.
   //Sugerencia: celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9

#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int farenheit=32;
    float celsius, i, a=5,b=9;

    do{
        celsius=(farenheit - 32) * (a/b);
        //printf("%.1f\n", celsius);

        printf("Grados farenheit: %d. Grados celsius: %.1f.", farenheit, celsius);
        fflush(stdin);

        farenheit=farenheit+2;

    }while(farenheit<=100);

return 0;
}```
````

Comment: No veo ningún problema https://tio.run/##TU9LDsIgEN1zionGhCpqbePCtLgx8RRukIKQIDVA40K9mEsvVttaq7Oaz/sNn584r@uxttxUhch9KHS5UFuEtA1wZtri6IagqXaWzAmrhA40TbJuK03JAnBhvK48AU2A0TU50k2GuntRwofeVg@jeNCBOaRJBFPAbHmMsgF5cY2dxKNJ8XrCHu4wWaxk0@4OdkR@MchX8o8qpam8wu0jNupTdPvBc0Yh6Q@Pq9JG/PLkdBXHLcuJUDkLcYYedf0G

Comment: Crea un [example].

Comment: @Mateo el enlace a Try it Online que proporcionas no contiene el mismo snippet código que es proporcionado en la pregunta original

Comment: @dev-t4d3 no es exactamente el mismo porque le cambié las cadenas para que sea más fácil de leer. [¿Así te parece bien?](https://tio.run/##TVDLDsIgELzzFRuNCdXa1hoPWvHqT3hBHpYEqQEaD8Zvr0Vp65zY2ZlZdtn6xljXzZVhuuUCjs5z1WT1CSFlPNypMjh5IegRakmtMLVQnmzL6stK3VAPTGinWpeCSoGSXXol@wp9@7z5uQOiiuAxBtawLRNYAqb5NalGZZ4/bD9P4tki28iLmaWDOYm5AYPmbClv3PS5Ayx4BpGNvp4bkkbdf@iQKaVuXY3DGcz/rGnz8bUqY//9rJUW01ZHsimKYLbCt9ZAUaF3130A)

Comment: Por cierto, [`fflush(stdin)` es comportamiento indefinido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/226500/169744).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parece que te esta faltando la secuencia de escape `\n`, nos cuentas que al añadirla tu programa comienza a actuar con un comportamiento indebido, seria bueno que des un ejemplo de lo que debería producir y lo que produce por ejemplo: 
 Obtengo esto (Nota F y C serán remplazados por los valores correspondientes>

```
Grados farenheit: <F>. Grados celsius: <C>.Grados farenheit: <F>. Grados celsius: <C>.
```

y espero obtener:

```
Grados farenheit: <F>. Grados celsius: <C>.
Grados farenheit: <F>. Grados celsius: <C>.
```

por aquí te dejo un ejemplo que esta funcionando correctamente

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int farenheit=32;
    float celsius, i, a=5,b=9;

    do {
        celsius=(farenheit - 32) * (a/b); // Podrias abstraer esto en una función si lo requieres

        printf("Grados farenheit: %d. Grados celsius: %.1f.\n", farenheit, celsius);
        fflush(stdin); // Esto es innecesario pero no cambia el resultado

        farenheit += 2; // Puedes usar += para agregar 2 a la variable

    } while (farenheit<=100);

    return 0;
}
```

con este código obtengo:

```
Grados farenheit: 32. Grados celsius: 0.0.
Grados farenheit: 34. Grados celsius: 1.1.
Grados farenheit: 36. Grados celsius: 2.2.
Grados farenheit: 38. Grados celsius: 3.3.
Grados farenheit: 40. Grados celsius: 4.4.
Grados farenheit: 42. Grados celsius: 5.6.
Grados farenheit: 44. Grados celsius: 6.7.
Grados farenheit: 46. Grados celsius: 7.8.
Grados farenheit: 48. Grados celsius: 8.9.
Grados farenheit: 50. Grados celsius: 10.0.
Grados farenheit: 52. Grados celsius: 11.1.
Grados farenheit: 54. Grados celsius: 12.2.
Grados farenheit: 56. Grados celsius: 13.3.
Grados farenheit: 58. Grados celsius: 14.4.
Grados farenheit: 60. Grados celsius: 15.6.
Grados farenheit: 62. Grados celsius: 16.7.
Grados farenheit: 64. Grados celsius: 17.8.
Grados farenheit: 66. Grados celsius: 18.9.
Grados farenheit: 68. Grados celsius: 20.0.
Grados farenheit: 70. Grados celsius: 21.1.
Grados farenheit: 72. Grados celsius: 22.2.
Grados farenheit: 74. Grados celsius: 23.3.
Grados farenheit: 76. Grados celsius: 24.4.
Grados farenheit: 78. Grados celsius: 25.6.
Grados farenheit: 80. Grados celsius: 26.7.
Grados farenheit: 82. Grados celsius: 27.8.
Grados farenheit: 84. Grados celsius: 28.9.
Grados farenheit: 86. Grados celsius: 30.0.
Grados farenheit: 88. Grados celsius: 31.1.
Grados farenheit: 90. Grados celsius: 32.2.
Grados farenheit: 92. Grados celsius: 33.3.
Grados farenheit: 94. Grados celsius: 34.4.
Grados farenheit: 96. Grados celsius: 35.6.
Grados farenheit: 98. Grados celsius: 36.7.
Grados farenheit: 100. Grados celsius: 37.8.
```