# Problema con fflush, variable no responde bien y programa no responde ante 1 respuesta especifica

Tags: c, string, variables

Tengo 2 dudas: La primera es Cuando hay que utilizar el fflush(stdin)?

Y la segunda:

Hay un ejercicio que me pide registrar el nombre, sexo, horas trabajadas y cuanto cobra por hora, que al final del ciclo me muestre su nombre, horas trabajadas y cuanto sera su sueldo (horas x cobra) y al final del ciclo sacar un promedio del sueldo de los hombres y de las mujeres.

El tema es que cuando ingreso los datos y al momento de  escoger un sexo, el programa solo anda bien con el sexo Masculino y el Femenino al ingresarlo da error

Por ejemplo:
Caso 1 = Ingreso el sexo en Masculino y luego otro en femenino. Al final me muestra solo el promedio masculino y el femenino en 0
Caso 2 = Ingreso el sexo femenino primero y termino el programa. Este se congela y no continua o me muestra el promedio.

````
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char nombre[100];
    char validador[] = "terminar";
    char sexo;
    int sueldoxhora, sueldo, horas, sumamasculino=0, sumafemenino=0, contadorM, contadorF, terminar, i;
    float sueldopromedioM=0, sueldopromedioF=0;

    printf("Ingrese su Nombre. Para finalizar programa ingrese Terminar: \n");
    scanf("%s", &nombre);
    fflush(stdin);

    terminar=strcmp(nombre,validador);
    i=1;

    while(terminar != 0 ){
        printf("Ingrese su sexo: Hombre: H . Mujer: M \n");
        scanf("%c", &sexo);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Ingrese las horas que trabajo: \n");
        scanf("%d", &horas);

        printf("Ingrese su sueldo por hora: \n");
        scanf("%d", &sueldo);

        if(sexo=='H'){
            sumamasculino=sumamasculino+sueldo;
            contadorM++;
        }else
            if(sexo=='M'){
                sumafemenino=sumafemenino+sueldo;
                contadorF++;
        }

        sueldoxhora=sueldo*horas;

        printf("\nNombre del Empleado: %s.\nHoras Trabajadas: %d.\nSueldo por Hora: %d.\nCantidad que cobrara: %d.\n", nombre, horas, sueldo, sueldoxhora);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Ingrese su Nombre. Para finalizar programa. Ingrese la letra X\n");
        gets(nombre);


        i=0;
        terminar=strcmp(nombre,validador);

    }

    if( i == 1){
        printf("No se ingreso ningun empleado");

    }else if( i == 0){

        sueldopromedioM=sumamasculino/contadorM;
        sueldopromedioF=sumafemenino/contadorF;

        printf("\nEl Sueldo Promedio de los Hombres es de: %.1f.\nY el de las mujeres es de: %.1f.", sueldopromedioM, sueldopromedioF);
    }
return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: En cuanto a tu primera pregunta, [ya existe respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/226500/169744). Respuesta corta: nunca. Es comportamiento indefinido. Así que centrate en la segunda parte de la pregunta para que no sea cerrada por duplicado o porque necesita ser más específica (hay varias preguntas en una).

Comment: Seguro que voy a decir una estupidez, pero ne debería ser: scanf("%s", &sexo);

Comment: @Marce no porque solo quiere un carácter. En todo caso sería `scanf("%1s", &sexo)` creo

Comment: @Mateo, gracias por iluminarme una vez más!!

Answer (score 0):

Usemos este ejemplo de entrada:

```
José H 10 12
María M 20 24
terminar
```

`scanf("%s", nombre)` lee hasta el primer espacio en blanco pero no lo quita. Inmediatamente se llama a `scanf("%c", &sexo)` lo cual lee el espacio.

La solución es consumir el espacio y puedes hacerlo agregando un espacio justo antes de `%c`:

```
scanf(" %c", &sexo);
```

Para leer números no hay problemas ya que siempre se descarta el espacio en blanco previo al número.

Otro detalle a tener en cuenta es que a diferencia de `scanf`, `gets` lee la línea completa. Sin embargo la primera vez que lees el nombre lo haces con `scanf` y dentro del ciclo con `gets`.

Cada vez que debas hacer lo mismo, hazlo de la misma forma. Sugiero que uses `scanf` para leer el nombre.

Para no repetir, puedes reescribir el ciclo de la siguiente manera:

```
while(1){
    printf("Ingrese su Nombre. Para finalizar programa ingrese Terminar: \n");
    scanf("%s", nombre);
    terminar = strcmp(nombre, validador);
    if (terminar == 0)
        break;

    printf("Ingrese su sexo: Hombre: H . Mujer: M \n");
    scanf(" %c", &sexo);

    printf("Ingrese las horas que trabajo: \n");
    scanf("%d", &horas);

    printf("Ingrese su sueldo por hora: \n");
    scanf("%d", &sueldo);      

    if(sexo=='H'){            
        sumamasculino += sueldo;
        contadorM++;
    }
    else if(sexo=='M'){
        sumafemenino += sueldo;
        contadorF++;
    }

    sueldoxhora=sueldo*horas;

    printf("\nNombre del Empleado: %s.\nSexo %c\nHoras Trabajadas: %d.\nSueldo por Hora: %d.\nCantidad que cobrara: %d.\n", nombre, sexo, horas, sueldo, sueldoxhora);

    i = 0;
}
```

---

Cabe mencionar también que:

- Tienes que inicializar tus contadores (a 0 normalmente).
- Las divisiones que se están realizando son de enteros por lo que pierdes los decimales.
- No necesitas una variable `i`, puedes ver si los 2 contadores dan 0.
- En una división de números de coma flotante obtendrás un error si intentas dividir 0 por 0.

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##hVRRb9owEH7PrzhlYpCSMUB7gtKXqYhNoqq0vkxjD27iQDrHZnayVav6g/awX9Efxs6OYwdKS1Sp@Hz@7u777i55t06S3e5NzhNWpRTOVZnmYrC5CNommfO1tgU5L6EgOe9FDwHgl2yIBC6KW0m/jYbD71NnPYNfhOUpSYWEGYQllUXOiQy9Byh6L@qjhlUVZam43whJYnuIQZ9UDIngpUZaItTQH@f1scGusTImSIO2laKgWI99t2@cN8aCFEQlFcu58KaMFpRbyzQwyL83OaO9kS1df1skpsx64Se@llRRfAhXhowBXBNJIMO0WP4Ha8Wga4lxsNTa9cYmPYEVD6Opg1QJ4YjYUWFsiW1dNpViUihKUmx7tUvsyW555xn0/AusI3JX@sN35Ict7YVitEITWJgY@B8GsKzuKOa8PJ41dBJM@61@Fr2CzIiqlYWfFYVSkltyJ14iItWIxjs6kaxRF7bYcNr9VbzaN5rWV0GLsp5OfjbrLrrRQ5utPer2e6Y/s7Gne06uaft9f/HoflGGaft4y26rr5oYrglPhJjvh/A1@5ma1b/PDJNHiFzxunMhpQwuiy2jCDyBjhqs@BdMEaVd8YUR7cYIRlKi8D7V9575hWHeWD8SXuqeNCIn4lYSd@V6OzYt5ua8GftW3lZBWxTy5XdBv7UIzuHYXF4J0CSbHhGATK4rDtQWFzpoJ4dD0KPjA10cjM7z5bLfEO@99tNjiPMTiHOL6OT3gPOj0l0ysBpcWwiUEZhQdnYV4F@KI9wZjDLk/yuWazxQzUJP9IFHeLgrl8@WpyNP0rKSXC/JR9jtPgv19Bc3xWgIo3GwJPLpH8FtMR7C@EPQLKP/).