# C++, Alguien me podría decir que hace esta línea de código?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Tengo duda con lo que hace esta siguiente línea, ya que como ven la coloque como un comentario y creo que no afecta nada al funcionamiento de este mismo, igual acepto correcciones en este mismo ya que estoy aprendiendo. Muchas gracias por su atención.

****`//archivoescritura.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&datos_alumno), sizeof(registro));`****

El código trata sobre la escritura de archivos

```
#include<iostream>//define el flujo cout
#include<stdlib.h>//define la funcion exit(1);
#include<string>//cadena de caracteres
#include<fstream>//para creacion, escritura y lectura de archivos, ofstream


using namespace std;

void Escribiendoarchivo();//creamos la funcion
//Creamos un registro

//con typedef le decimos lo siguiente, en este caso cada struct que queramos con estas especificaciones, lo llamaremos como regalumno
typedef struct registro{
    char matricula[15];
    char nombre[20];
    char apellido[20];
    int nota;
}regalumno;

int main(){
    system("color 1F");

    Escribiendoarchivo();//llamamos a la funcion

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//Escribimos lo que hara la funcion
void Escribiendoarchivo(){ 
char nombrearchivo[30];
regalumno datos_alumno; //esto gracias al typedef, regalumno nos servira para llamar a otro registro de una forma diferente

cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del archivo al que quiere escribir: ";
cin >> nombrearchivo;

ofstream archivoescritura(nombrearchivo, ios::app | ios::binary);

if(!archivoescritura){
    cerr << "Error: no se puede abrir el archivo de salida"<<endl;
    exit(1);
}
else{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\t\nIngrese los datos del alumno"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"<<endl;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"\tMatricula: ";cin.getline(datos_alumno.matricula,15,'\n');
    cout<<"\tNombre: ";cin.getline(datos_alumno.nombre,20,'\n');
    cout<<"\tApellido: ";cin.getline(datos_alumno.apellido,20,'\n');
    cout<<"\tNota: "; fflush(stdin); cin>>datos_alumno.nota;
    cout<<"\t~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"<<endl;
    //archivoescritura.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&datos_alumno), sizeof(registro));
    archivoescritura.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. [No uses `fflush(stdin)`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/226500/169744). Si necesitas consumir un carácter usa cualquiera de las funciones de [`fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream). Por ejemplo `ignore`. Por cierto, está mal mezclar las funciones de entrada de C y C++.

Comment: Como estás en C++, te aconsejo usar la cabecera propia `cstdlib` en lugar de `stdlib.h`, que es de C

Comment: Muchas gracias a los que ayudaron con mi duda, y a los que me dieron consejos para lograr un mejor codigo. Sin duda tengo que aprender más de este mundo.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo que cojas la buena costumbre de visitar documentaciones oficiales para aprender más sobre funcionalidades/metodos etc del lenguaje que estas aprendiendo.

Aunque preguntar está muy bien... visitar, como digo, las documentaciones oficuales es parte del día a día de un programador.

A si que, por partes.

// archivoescritura.write(...)

Se esta llamando al metodo write de una variable del tipo

// ofstream archivoescritura(...)

Puedes buscar entonces por ejemplo (en google): c++ ofstream write
Cuyo primer resultado [es este](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/)

Dentro de este write, es llama a `reinterpret_cast` que también hay una documentacion muy clara al respeto [aquí](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reinterpret_cast-in-c-type-casting-operators/)

Todo apunta a que se escribira (write) en el archivo `archivoescritura` lo que sea que devuelva el `reinterpret_cast` cuando le pasas esta información que le pasas: `(&datos_alumno), sizeof(registro)`

Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que toda la información no es nada más que una serie de 0s y 1s.

El tipo de la variable le indica al compilador cómo debe interpretar esa información.

Con `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&datos_alumno)` sigues teniendo un puntero pero ahora de tipo `char`. Es decir, el compilador debe interpretar lo que haya en la dirección de memoria apuntada como un caracter.

---

La información se guarda como una secuencia de bytes. Simplemente porque la memoria asigna una dirección de memoria diferente a cada byte.

Si bien el estándar de C++ no impone ningún tamaño fijo para los [tipos fundamentales](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), normalmente el tipo `char` ocupa un solo **byte** en memoria.

El método [`write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) recibe un puntero a los caracteres y la cantidad a escribir. Pero como cada `char` es un byte, también se puede usar para escribir bytes.

El propósito de la conversión es engañar a la función. Así escribirá los bytes que queramos.

Con `sizeof(registro)` obtienes el tamaño de la estructura en bytes.

---

#### Dato curioso

[`ostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) en realidad es un alias para `basic_ostream<char>`.

Así que otra forma de guardar un único tipo de dato en un archivo es cambiar el parámetro de la plantilla por tal tipo. Por ejemplo:

```
basic_ofstream<registro> archivo(nombrearchivo, ios::app | ios::binary);

...

archivo.write(&datos_alumno, 1);
```

Nota que ahora el tipo del primer parámetro del método `write` es `registro*` ya que depende del parámetro que reciba la plantilla.