# Varieble int recibe información de tipo char:

Tags: c, char, int

Soy nuevo en este mundo de la programación.
Estoy haciendo un ejercicio para la facultad y no entiendo por qué al poner el segundo número, (es decir, luego de escribir 's' por primera vez para poner otro número) la variable entera `num` puede recibir información de tipo `char`.
Si escribo 'm', por ejemplo, salta a la siguiente etapa aunque sea de tipo `int`. Esto pasa también con la confirmación de poner otro número (a partir del segundo número, escribir 'm' en vez de 's' o 'n').

Si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería mucho.
Gracias

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 20

int main()
{

    int num = 0;
    int pares[N];
    int impares[N];
    int countP = 0;
    int countI = 0;
    int cont = 0;
    char continuar;

    do
    {
        puts("\nEscriba 20 números para analizar si son pares o impares.");
        do
        {
            puts("Escriba un número entero mayor a 0.");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d", &num);
            if (num <= 0)
                puts("Lo ingresado no corresponde con lo pedido.");

        } while (num <= 0);

        if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            pares[cont] = num;
            countP++;
        }
        if (num % 2 != 0)
        {
            impares[cont] = num;
            countI++;
        }

        do
        {
            puts("Si desea continuar con otro número presione 'S', sino, presione 'N'");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", &continuar);
            continuar = toupper(continuar);
        } while (continuar != 'S' && continuar != 'N');
        cont++;

    } while (continuar == 'S' && cont < N);

    if (countP > 0)
    {
        printf("\nLa cantidad de números pares es de %d \n  Y son los siguientes:", countP);
        for (int x = 0; x < cont; x++)
        {
            printf("%d", pares[x]);
        }
    }
    else
        puts("\nNo hay números pares.");

    if (countI > 0)
    {
        printf("\nLa cantidad de números impares es de %d \nY son los siguientes:", countI);
        for (int x = 0; x < cont; x++)
        {
            printf("%d", impares[x]);
        }
    }
    else
        puts("\nNo hay números impares.");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Es que en "c" , un char de ciertanforma lo trata como "int"

Comment: Bienvenido. Aprovechemos que estás comenzando para aprender bien. No uses `fflush(stdin)`. Mira [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/226494/169744) para entender mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Si insertas caracteres que no corresponden con el formato %i o %d, el resultado es impredecible, la función *scanf()* funciona de la siguiente manera:

- intenta leer, desde la entrada del teclado, una secuencia que represente un valor de entero positivo o negativo (%i puede leer números en diferentes bases).
- ignora las tabulaciones y espacios que podría haber al inicio de la secuencia.
- si encuentra un carácter valido para hacer la conversión a entero (0-9, signos - y +) continua con la lectura secuencialmente hasta que se encuentra con un carácter invalido. (aunque esos caracteres se ignoren, podrían seguir almacenadas en el buffer de entrada y provocar un comportamiento no deseado, ver el código de abajo).
- si de primeras no se proporciona ningún caracter valido para hacer la conversión, el valor no se asigna a la variable y la función devuelve un valor que represente el fallo de la lectura (el valor difiere entre compiladores). Estos caracteres como en el caso anterior, podrían seguir dentro del buffer de entrada.

Considera el siguiente codigo:

```
int main () {
    int i;
    scanf("%i", &i);
    printf("el valor de i es: %i \n", i);
    char str[N];
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("La cadena ingresada es: %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Si inserto por teclado una secuencia de caracteres como '123abc' el entero 123 se leerá correctamente y será asignado a la variable, pero los caracteres 'abc' permanecerán en el buffer de entrada y a la hora de leer la cadena de caracteres que viene después, tomara esos caracteres y los asignara sin siquiera poder insertar la cadena por teclado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la asignación al entero ocurrió correctamente porque la función encontró valores validos de primeras, si probamos el caso en que tenemos valores invalidos al principio como '123abc':

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No solo asigno incorrectamente el entero, sino que toda la secuencia de caracteres quedo en el buffer de entrada, por lo que me tomo esos caracteres y los asigno a la cadena 'str' sin mi control, como en el caso anterior...

En el caso de que pases valores numéricos a variables que reciben char, lo que ocurrirá es que si es solo 1 numero entonces este será pasado a caracter (un numero también es un caracter, pero no todos los caracteres son números) y esto seria correcto, pero si este tiene mas de 1 digito se leerá solo el primero, y el resto de los dígitos que queden seguirán en el buffer de entrada, produciendo comportamientos inesperados como los que te señale anteriormente.

En resumen, aunque a primeras parece que no pasa nada, debes evitar a toda costa recibir valores que no correspondan con el formato especificado en la funcion scanf(), puedes usar el valor de retorno de *scanf()* para validar. tambien puedes eliminar los datos del buffer de entrada con este codigo, colocandolo despues de donde crees puede haber una lectura erronea:

```
int c;
while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF ) { }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus comentarios y respuestas. Ahora entiendo un poco más de esto. Les agradezco.

Answer (score 0):

Yo ..

- Utilizaría un metodo como el que han compartido en este hilo para vaciar el buffer de entrada, porque usar fflush(stdin) es una mala practica.

*(A tener en cuenta que actualmente, es obsoleto el uso de fflush(stdin), solo puede resultar si se intenta con compiladores antiguos, y ademas esta desaconsejado para el buffer de entrada)*

- Asignaría la variable que vaya a usar scanf(), a -1 cada vez, si es para un entero, y a X, si es ara un caracter, antes de volver a hacer scanf().
- Y además, verificaría, que scanf() no me devuelva un valor de error en la entrada de teclado, de acuerdo a los valores que puedo esperar me devuelva scanf() como tipo o nivel de error.

Y si no fuera asi, que estuviera todo OK, repetiría el bucle, para evitar que se salte de introducir y tener un valor correcto como entero, o como S/N.

Comment: Tal vez no sepas que [no es buena idea usar `fflush(stdin)`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226494/para-que-sirve-flush-en-c). Si necesitas alternativas, [aquí hay varias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io), entre ellas `getchar` y `fgetc`.

Comment: Comprendo. Gracias por decirmelo. No lo sabía, aunque, siempre me interesa saber mas, y mejorar.

Comment: Me alegro. Ya es hora de que dejemos de usar porque si `fflush(stdin)`, al parecer muchos estamos mal acostumbrados a usarlo.

Comment: Ah, y si conozco esas dos ptras funciones, claro que, trato.tambien siempre de asegurar todo este uso de funciones en C.

Comment: Ya veo, en el articulo sobre el asunto. Gracias.