# Programa conversor romano a arábigo y viceversa no funciona correctamente

Tags: array, c

Tengo ese c que convierte de arábigo a romano y viceversa, mediante un menú

El programa compila, pero la conversión de romano a arábigo solo funciona con algunos números

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>

char * de_arabigo_a_romano(int numeroArabigo);
char * a2roman (int valor, char *c1, char *c2, char *c3);
void mostrar_resultado_de_arabigo_a_romano(char roman []);
int de_romano_a_arabigo(char letraR);
void mostrar_resultado_de_romano_a_arabigo(int numR);

int numR = 0;
int decR = 0;
int cont = 0;
int cont3R = 0;
int numsR[15] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
char letraR = ' ';
static char roman[15] = {0};
static char rRoman[15] = {0};
int numeroArabigo = 1;

int main()
{
    int op;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Este programa convierte de n£meros ar bigos a romanos y viceversa\n");
        printf("Ingrese la opci¢n deseada\n");
        printf("   1. De ar bigo a romano\n");
        printf("   2. De romano a ar bigo\n");
        printf("   3. Salir\n");
        printf("Elija una opci¢n (1-3): \n");
        scanf("%d",&op);
        switch (op)
        {
        case 1:
            de_arabigo_a_romano(numeroArabigo);
            mostrar_resultado_de_arabigo_a_romano(roman);
            break;
        case 2:
            de_romano_a_arabigo(letraR);
            mostrar_resultado_de_romano_a_arabigo (numR);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Gracias, vuelva pronto\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Opci¢n no v lida\n");
            exit (0);
        }
        printf("Presione enter para continuar\n");
        getch();
    }
    while (op!=3);

    return 0;
}

char * de_arabigo_a_romano(int numeroArabigo)
{
    int result;
    do
    {
        printf ("Ingrese un entero en el rango de 1 a 3000: \n\t");

        scanf ("%d", &numeroArabigo);
    }
    while ((numeroArabigo < 1) || (numeroArabigo > 3000));

    if ((numeroArabigo <= 3000) && (numeroArabigo >= 1000))
    {
        result = numeroArabigo / 1000;
        strcat (roman, a2roman(result, "M", " ", " "));
        numeroArabigo -= (result * 1000);
    }

    if ((numeroArabigo < 1000) && (numeroArabigo >= 100))
    {
        result = numeroArabigo / 100;
        strcat (roman, a2roman(result, "C", "D", "M"));
        numeroArabigo -= (result * 100);
    }

    if ((numeroArabigo < 100) && (numeroArabigo >= 10))
    {
        result = numeroArabigo / 10;
        strcat (roman, a2roman(result, "X", "L", "C"));
        numeroArabigo -= (result * 10);
    }

    if ((numeroArabigo < 10) && (numeroArabigo >= 1))
    {
        strcat (roman, a2roman(numeroArabigo, "I", "V", "X"));
    }
    return roman;
}

char *a2roman (int valor, char *c1, char *c2, char *c3)
{
    int i;

    char *retRoman = rRoman;

    if ((valor >= 1) && (valor <= 3))
    {
        for (i = 0; i < valor; i++)
            strcat (rRoman, c1);
    }

    if ((valor >= 5) && (valor <= 8))
    {
        strcat (rRoman, c2);

        for (i = 0; i < (valor - 5); i++)
            strcat (rRoman, c1);
    }

    if (valor == 4)
    {
        strcat (rRoman, c1);
        strcat (rRoman, c2);
    }

    if (valor == 9)
    {
        strcat (rRoman, c1);
        strcat (rRoman, c3);
    }

    return retRoman;
}

void mostrar_resultado_de_arabigo_a_romano(char roman[])
{
    printf ("El n£mero romano es: \n");
    for (int i = 0 ; roman[i] != '\0' ; i++){
        printf("%c",roman[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(roman);
}

int de_romano_a_arabigo(char letraR)
{
    printf ("Ingrese un n£mero romano en el rango de I a MMMCMXCIX:\n");
    /* Leer desde el teclado hasta que aparezca un <ENTER> */
    fflush(stdin);
    while ((letraR != '\n') && (cont < 15))
    {
        letraR = toupper(getchar());

        switch (letraR)
        {
        case 'V':
        case 'L':
        case 'D':
            if ((cont > 0) && (roman[cont - 1] == letraR))
            {
                printf ("\nArgumento no v lido");
                sleep (1000);
                exit (0);
            }

            else
            {
                roman[cont++] = letraR;
            }
            break;
        case 'I':
        case 'X':
        case 'C':
        case 'M':
            if (cont3R <= 3)
            {
                roman[cont++] = letraR;
            }
            cont3R++;
            if ((cont3R > 3) && (roman[cont - 2] == letraR))
            {
                printf ("\nArgumento no v lido");
                sleep (1000);
                exit (0);
            }
            if ((cont > 1) && ((cont3R > 3) || (roman[cont - 2] != letraR)))
            {
                cont3R = 1;
            }
            break;

        case '\n':
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nArgumento no v lido");
            sleep (1000);
            exit (0);
        }
    }

    for (cont3R = 0; cont3R <= cont; cont3R++)
    {
        switch (roman[cont3R])
        {
        case 'I':
            numsR[cont3R] = 1;
            break;
        case 'V':
            numsR[cont3R] = 5;
            break;
        case 'X':
            numsR[cont3R] = 10;
            break;
        case 'L':
            numsR[cont3R] = 50;
            break;
        case 'C':
            numsR[cont3R] = 100;
            break;
        case 'D':
            numsR[cont3R] = 500;
            break;
        case 'M':
            numsR[cont3R] = 1000;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (cont3R = 0; cont3R <= cont; cont3R++)
    {
        if (numsR[cont3R] >= numsR[cont3R + 1])
        {
            decR = numsR[cont3R];
        }

        if ((numsR[cont3R] == (numsR[cont3R + 1] / 10))
                || (numsR[cont3R] == (numsR[cont3R + 1] / 5)))
        {
            decR = numsR[cont3R + 1] - numsR[cont3R];
            cont3R++;
        }
        if (decR < numsR[cont3R + 1])
        {
            printf ("\nArgumento no v lido");
            sleep (1000);
            exit (0);
        }
        numR += decR;
    }
    return numR;
}

void mostrar_resultado_de_romano_a_arabigo (int numR)
{
    printf ("El valor es %d\n", numR);
}
```

Comment: Parte de tu confusión se debe a que tienes variables locales llamadas igual a tus variables globales. Son variables diferentes y las locales tienen prevalencia sobre las globales, así que el resultado se pierde. Además en tus funciones devuelves valores que nunca usas. Por cierto, [`fflush(stdin)` no sirve de nada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/226494/169744) y no deberías imprimir todos los caracteres de `roman` sino verás caracteres extraños. Para evitarlo debes parar cuando encuentres un carácter nulo.