# El programa se cierra solo tras ejecutar free

Tags: c

tengo dos problemas con esta función

```
char *obtenerContrasenia(){
    int i = 0;
    char c, *contrasenia;

    contrasenia = (char *) calloc(PASS, sizeof(char));

    if(contrasenia == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error en asignacion de memoria.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nEscribe la contrasena (maximo 15 caracteres): ");
    fflush(stdin);

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && i < PASS){        // Recogemos caracter a caracter para controlar el tamaño de entrada
        contrasenia[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    contrasenia[i] = '\0';       // Añadimos el \0 final

    // Comprobamos si el tamaño es correcto, en caso de no serlo, limpiamos la cadena y volvemos a llamar a la función
    if(strlen(contrasenia) > PASS-1){
        fprintf(stderr, "La contrasena excede los 15 caracteres.");
        printf("esto se ejecuta\n");      // PRUEBAS
        free(contrasenia);   // aquí el programa se CIERRA SOLO
        printf("no llega a ejecutarse");  // PRUEBAS
        obtenerContrasenia();
    }

    if(strlen(contrasenia) == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "La contrasena no puede estar vacio.");
        free(contrasenia);
        obtenerContrasenia();
    } 

    return contrasenia;
}
```

El ***primero de ellos*** es como hacer que esta función no sea recursiva ya que no encuentro manera de conseguirlo.

El ***segundo de ellos*** es que, tras la ejecución de `free` el programa se cierra únicamente cuando se ejecuta el condicional `strlen(contrasenia) > PASS -1` en el caso de que sea cero o no se ejecute ninguno de los condicionales no hay problema.

Intuyo que el problema está en la recursividad y por ese motivo quiero cambiarlo ya que no me parece una forma elegante de resolver este problema, pero es curioso porque tengo otras funciones así en el código y no tienen este problema y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Descubre [por qué no usar `fflush(stdin)`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/226494/169744).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> El ***primero de ellos*** es como hacer que esta función no sea recursiva ya que no encuentro manera de conseguirlo.

Simplemente no llames a la función `obtenerContrasenia` dentro de `obtenerContrasenia` ¡no más recursión!.

Por lo que veo en tu código recurres a la recursión es porque quieres que se siga llamando `obtenerContrasenia` cuando la función falla… pero la manera de hacerlo no es mediante recursión. Toda llamada a `obtenerContrasenia` debe hacerse fuera de la misma función y la decisión de volver a llamarla debe hacerse también fuera, así que debes informar al llamante de que la función ha fallado, una práctica habitual es devolver `NULL`:

```c
char *obtenerContrasenia(){
    char *contrasenia = (char *)calloc(PASS, sizeof(char));

    if(contrasenia == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error en asignacion de memoria.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nEscribe la contrasena (maximo 15 caracteres): ");
    fflush(stdin);

    char c;
    int i;
    // Recogemos caracter a caracter para controlar el tamaño de entrada
    while(((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (i < PASS)) {
        contrasenia[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    if(strlen(contrasenia) == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "La contrasena no puede estar vacio.");
        free(contrasenia);
        return NULL;
    }

    return contrasenia;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *contrasenia = NULL;
    // Repetir mientras no se haya obtenido una contrasenia
    while (!contrasenia)
        contrasenia = obtenerContrasenia();

    printf("La contrasenia es '%s'", contrasenia);

    return 0;
}
```

Observarás que he mutilado tu función `obtenerContrasenia`, lo he hecho por los siguientes motivos:

- [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) devuelve la memoria inicializada a cero, por lo que no es necesario añadir un `'\0'` después de la lectura.
- No hace falta comprobar que la longitud de la contraseña no supera `PASS`, ya que sólo capturas datos hasta que has leído al menos `PASS` elementos.

Respecto al cierre tras `free` apuesto a que se debe a una corrupción de memoria: Has escrito más allá de la memoria reservada por `calloc`, probablemente al añadir la marca de fin de cadena (`'\0'`).

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya funciona perfectamente. ¿Sólo me queda una pequeña duda, en el main no habría que hacer ```free(contrasenia)``` ?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón: en `main` falta ese `free`.