# Llenar los campos de un struct con for. c++

Tags: c++

Trato de llenar los campos de una serie de estructuras, pero cuando le pido al usuario cadenas de caracteres, mediante la función cin.getline(), se salta varios campos que le pido que solicite.

Estoy seguro de usar todas las librerías correctas (iostream y string) y el nombre de espacio correcto (std).

```
struct corredor {
  char  nombre[50];
  int   edad;
  char  sexo[10];
  char  club[20];
}corredores[20];

int main() {
  int i, m;
  std::cout << "¿Cuántos corredores van a participar? ";  std::cin >> m;

  for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    cout<< "Corredor Nº " << i+1 << '\n';
    cout << "Nombre: "; cin.getline(corredores[i].nombre,50,'\n');
    cout << "Edad: ";   cin >> corredores[i].edad;
    cout << "Sexo: ";   cin.getline(corredores[i].sexo,10,'\n');
    cout << "Club: ";   cin.getline(corredores[i].club,20,'\n');
   }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Porque es necesario usar el comando cin.ignore() después de usar "cin >>" y luego recién usar el cin.getline(char\*,size)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193829/porque-es-necesario-usar-el-comando-cin-ignore-despu%c3%a9s-de-usar-cin-y-lue)

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que **cin >>** deja en el buffer el salto de linea, '\n'.
Entonces, **getline()** lo primero que lee es el buffer de entrada.
Dado que **getline()** lee hasta encontrar un salto de linea '\n', no llega a leer nada.

Puedes colocar un **cin.ignore();** justo después del **cin >>**, para ignorar el salto de línea que se queda en el buffer de entrada.