# ¿Por qué no me muestre el dato de sexo?, me sale en blanco

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
struct Corredor{
    char nombre[30];
    int edad;
    char sexo[20];
    char club[20];
}corredor[100];

int main(){
    
    int n_corredores;
    int i;
    
    cout<<"Digite el numero de corredores: ";
    cin>>n_corredores;
    
    for(i=0;i<n_corredores;i++){
        cin.ignore(256,'\n');//basiar los datos del buffer
        cout<<"Nombre: ";
        cin.getline(corredor[i].nombre,30,'\n');
        cout<<"Edad: ";
        cin>>corredor[i].edad;
        cout<<"Sexo: ";
        cin.getline(corredor[i].sexo,20,'\n');
        cin.ignore(256,'\n');//basiar los datos del buffer
        cout<<"Club: ";
        cin.getline(corredor[i].club,20,'\n');
    }
    
    cout<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n_corredores;i++){
        if(corredor[i].edad<=18){
            cout<<"Categoria juvenil"<<endl;
            cout<<"Nombre: "<<corredor[i].nombre<<endl;
            cout<<"Edad: "<<corredor[i].edad<<endl;
            cout<<"Sexo: "<<corredor[i].sexo<<endl;
            cout<<"Club: "<<corredor[i].club<<endl; 
        }
        else if(corredor[i].edad<=40){
            cout<<"Categoria señor"<<endl;
            cout<<"Nombre: "<<corredor[i].nombre<<endl;
            cout<<"Edad: "<<corredor[i].edad<<endl;
            cout<<"Sexo: "<<corredor[i].sexo<<endl;
            cout<<"Club: "<<corredor[i].club<<endl; 
        }
        else if(corredor[i].edad>40){
            cout<<"Categoria veterano"<<endl;
            cout<<"Nombre: "<<corredor[i].nombre<<endl;
            cout<<"Edad: "<<corredor[i].edad<<endl;
            cout<<"Sexo: "<<corredor[i].sexo<<endl;
            cout<<"Club: "<<corredor[i].club<<endl; 
        }
    }
    
    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Este es el ejercicio al problema

Hacer una estructura llamada corredor, en el cual se tendran los siguientes campos:
Nombre, edad, sexo, club, pedir datos al usuario para un corredor, y asta una categoria
de competicion:

- Juvenil <= 18 años
- Señor <= 40 años
- Veterano > 40 años
  Posteriormente imprimir todos los datos del corredor, incluso su categoria de competicion.

[image: Consola]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Porque es necesario usar el comando cin.ignore() después de usar "cin >>" y luego recién usar el cin.getline(char\*,size)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193829/porque-es-necesario-usar-el-comando-cin-ignore-despu%c3%a9s-de-usar-cin-y-lue)

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontre el error, el cin.ignore hay que ponerlo arriba de la variable sexo y no abajo como lo habia puesto

```
for(i=0;i<n_corredores;i++){
        cin.ignore(256,'\n');//basiar los datos del buffer
        cout<<"Nombre: ";
        cin.getline(corredor[i].nombre,30,'\n');
        cout<<"Edad: ";
        cin>>corredor[i].edad;
        cin.ignore(256,'\n');//basiar los datos del buffer
        cout<<"Sexo: ";
        cin.getline(corredor[i].sexo,20,'\n');
        cout<<"Club: ";
        cin.getline(corredor[i].club,20,'\n');
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Alguien me puede decir porque, no entiendo como funciona muy bien el cin.ignore