# ¿Porque no me imprime la primera letra de un string en c++?

Tags: c++, string

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio para la facultad en c++. Le solicito al usuario que ingrese 2 string por teclado, uno con el nombre de la distribuidora y otro con el nombre del cliente, y después lo muestro por pantalla. Agregue la librerira string, las variables son de ese tipo y use getline y cin.ignore antes de cada una. El problema es que después cuando lo muestra por pantalla no sale la primera letra de ambos strings. No se si estoy usando mal el getline. Puse cin.ignore en ambos casos pero sigue saliendo mal. Este es el codigo:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    string nombre_distribuidora, nombre_cliente;
    int precio_zapato, cantidad_pares, forma_pago, monto_total, aux, total_pagar;
    
    cout<<"-------------------------DISTRIBUIDORA DE ZAPATOS-----------------";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre de la distribuidora: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,nombre_distribuidora);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"DATOS DEL CLIENTE";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre y Apellido: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, nombre_cliente);
    cout<<"Ingrese el precio de lista del zapato: $";
    cin>>precio_zapato;
    cout<<"Ingrese cantidad de pares: ";
    cin>>cantidad_pares;
    cout<<"Ingrese la forma de pago."<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Contado"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. 6 Cuotas"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. 12 Cuotas"<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese opcion 1, 2 o 3: ";
    cin>>forma_pago;
    cout<<endl;
    
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"DISTRIBUIDORA: "<<nombre_distribuidora<<endl;
    cout<<"CLIENTE: "<<nombre_cliente<<endl;
    cout<<"CANTIDAD DE PARES: "<<cantidad_pares<<endl;
    cout<<"PRECIO DE LISTA: $"<<precio_zapato<<endl;
    
    aux = 0;
    monto_total = 0;
    total_pagar = 0;
    
    switch (forma_pago){
        
    case 1:
        
        cout<<"FORMA DE PAGO: CONTADO."<<endl;  
        
        monto_total = precio_zapato * cantidad_pares;
        aux =  (monto_total * 5) / 100;
        total_pagar = monto_total - aux;

        cout<<"DESCUENTO: $"<<aux<<endl;
        cout<<"TOTAL A PAGAR: $"<<total_pagar; break;
            
    case 2:
        
        cout<<"FORMA DE PAGO: 6 Cuotas."<<endl; 
        
        monto_total = precio_zapato * cantidad_pares;
        total_pagar = monto_total; 
        
        cout<<"TOTAL A PAGAR: $"<<total_pagar; break;
    case 3:
        
        cout<<"FORMA DE PAGO: 12 Cuotas."<<endl;    
        
        monto_total = precio_zapato * cantidad_pares;
        aux =  (monto_total * 10) / 100;
        total_pagar = monto_total + aux;
        
        cout<<"DESCUENTO: $"<<aux<<endl;
        cout<<"TOTAL A PAGAR: $"<<total_pagar; break;
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Será por el uso de `cin.ignore`? Solo debes usar esa función cuando has usado `cin >>` y quieres usar `getline`. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/193846/169744

Comment: Si, era eso! saque los 2 cin.ignore y funciono. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin.ignore` se utiliza para descartar caracteres del buffer de entrada. Para que el descarte funcione debe haber caracteres en el buffer de entrada... y ese no es tu caso:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    string nombre_distribuidora, nombre_cliente;
    int precio_zapato, cantidad_pares, forma_pago, monto_total, aux, total_pagar;
    
    cout<<"-------------------------DISTRIBUIDORA DE ZAPATOS-----------------";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre de la distribuidora: ";
    cin.ignore();
```

La llamada a `cin.ignore` se produce antes de pedirle ningún dato al usuario. Lo que sucede entonces es que el programa se bloquea hasta que el método `ignore` termine su misión, que en este caso consiste en eliminar un caracter del buffer de entrada.

No necesitas llamar a este método antes de la primera lectura, ya que en ese punto el buffer de entrada estará necesariamente limpio.

Lo que sucede con el resto de lecturas es que los separadores (salto de línea, tabulador, espacio) que se encuentren tras el dato leído se dejan en el buffer de entrada. Afortunadamente la inmensa mayoría de los usos de `cin` contemplan esta posibilidad y descartan dichos caracteres.

La mala noticia es que `getline` no se incluye en esa lista.

Aun así, lo dicho, su uso antes de la primera lectura es, como te he dicho, contraproducente.

Para el resto de usos, contempla actualizar la siguiente llamada:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
```

Esta es quizás la llamada más común y te permite descartar todo lo que se encuentre en el buffer de entrada hasta llegar al primer salto de línea, que también será descartado

Comment: ahhh claro, los dos primeros datos que pido por teclado son con getline, como no pedí nada usando cin, no necesito agregar el cin.ignore en ninguno de los 2 getline. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

si no recuerdo mal, lo que puede estar ocurriendo es que al utilizar `cin.ignore()` sin ningún argumento, interpreta el primer carácter que encuentra y lo almacena en el buffer anterior, por lo tanto solo te muestra el resto de carácteres.

`cin.ignore()` puede recibir dos argumentos, el primero es el número de carácteres a extraer, y el segundo es el carácter delimitador.

Por ejemplo, `cin. ignore(5,'s')` ignorará hasta 5 carácteres o hasta llegar a la letra 's'.

Para tu propósito, puedes utilizarlo de esta forma:

```
cin.ignore(0, '\n');
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda,

Saludos

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias!! Probé con lo que me dijiste y funciono! :)